# Replacement using /. and two parts, one for variables and one for values

Tags: syntax

How do I evaluate, e.g. $3x+2y+z$, if I have $(x,y,z)$-values defined by a variable

```
a = {4, 5, 6}
```

I could do it with

```
expr = 3x + 2y + z;
expr /. {x->a[[1]], y->a[[2]], z->a[[3]]}
```

but there must be a smarter and shorter way to do it.

I tried ways like

```
expr /. {x, y, z} -> a
expr /. ({x, y, z} -> a)
```

but it was incorrect.
TIA

Comment: You need `Thread` like this: `3 x + 2 y + z /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> a]`. But even better would be to store your expression , linear in {x,y,z}, as the vector `{3,2,1}`. Then you could just do a dot product `{3,2,1}.{4,5,6}`

Comment: Or, if you are 'stuck' with `expr` (and you are as lazy as I am), you could get the dot product as follows: `a.Coefficient[#,Variables@#]&[expr]` => 28

Comment: Probably too late to get it marked as a dupe, but it probably should be, instead just closed.